# React state updated in child component but not in parent

Tags: reactjs

I am aware that changing the state is asynchronous and requires using the previous state.
But lately I have encountered a strange problem. After the state is modified the change is visible in the child (grand-child in fact) component but during callback to the parent the change is not visible there.
Here is the pseudocode

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);


  ... some method
  const changeState = (...) => {
    setItems( items => [...items, {id: 100, value: "Test"}]);
  }

  const callback = (id) => {
    const v = items.find( i => i.id == id );
// ERROR: v is undefined
  }

  return(<Child items={items} callback={callback} />);
}

const Child = ({items, callback) => {
...
  const onClick = () => {
    callback(100);
  }
...
}
```

The scenario is as follows:

1. The changeState method is called in Parent
2. the Child is rendered with the correct data
3. when the Item is rendered it has a onClick method with it's id as a param
4. onClick in Child is called
5. callback is called in the parent with id (which had been passed from Parent to Child)
6. there is an error because ... id does not exist in the Parent's state.

Any ideas where to look for the source of the problem?

Comment: in the comment you said `ERROR: v is undefined`, did you mean `id is undefined`?

Comment: No. Id is passed correctly but when the callback searches the state variable for this id no data is found :(

Comment: Also, it is some kind of a race condition. This problem happens, is not permanent!

Comment: It's not very clear what could be causing the issue. I don't see any obvious issues with the posted code. Is it possible for you to reproduce the issue you are experiencing through something like code sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with CHess

Your code semms to be correct in my eyes. And as you pointed out, the parent component must have contained the valid `items`state at some point. Otherwise it could not update it in the child component.

One thing I thought of:
Could it be that the `setItems` function is called from somewhere else? This could explain the strange behaviour.

I think a more complete code example could help getting to the bottom of this.